# Running capybara with nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, cucumber, bdd, capybara

Is is possible to run capybara with nginx and passenger? instead or webrick? Capybara is installed with cucumber in a rails app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easy - the only thing you have to do is to switch your mind - neither capybara nor cucumber are not tied to local environment you can test application that is located in internet and it will not care about it - you can even test google.com if you want.

For your particular problem you'll have to set

```
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.server_port = 8000 # or whatever port is your instance of nginx is configured to serve
Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com' # if your instance is running on remote machine, else just drop it and capybara will use localhost
```

You can easily control restarting of your application using cucumber hooks, you can configure it to restart before each test or before test suite. (See [cucumber wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks)) Within hook you'll have to issue `FileUtils.touch tmp/restart.txt` command. The same with database - you can manually setup hook to truncate it whenever it is needed (See [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem)

Comment: Thanks iafonov. Is there an alternative to database cleaner for non rails databases? My java app uses a mysql database.

Comment: Do you have an ORM on Java or Ruby side? Anyway you can easily implement naive truncation in Java or in Ruby by getting list of tables and issuing delete commands or just load fresh dump before each test (but it could be pain in the ass to maintain it in up-to-date state)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without an orm? I don't have acces to an orm

Comment: If you have an access to db, you can issue `show tables` and then iterate over returned dataset and issue `delete from #{table_name}` query