# How to run Capybara specs on Nginx+Node+Rails servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, nginx, capybara

An application is running on Rails (localhost:3000) + Node (localhost:8080) servers and the Nginx is used to redirect requests either to Rails server or Node.

In Nginx config file we have set constant IP (**nginx.localhost**) to send requests to Nginx.
Also the Rails and Node servers IP are constant for nginx.

And now there is a problem to run tests on this environment.
I need to run tests with this **nginx.localhost** as a root_path or Capybara.app_host so that I could test application via Nginx.

Do you have any ideas? All what came to my mind was to update nginx config file with port and server generated by rspec on suite start.
But this is a bit awkward.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7047972/477037

Comment: @Stefan, thanks, but no. The issue is that I need access to the test database during test execution. Also I will need to launch tests on Circle CI.

Comment: Did you get this one solved?